# Rails 4 - how do I get the images path of an image in production with a hash on the end?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-4, hash, asset-pipeline

I want to reference an image in the public folder that has been precompiled in prod. But, it seems that all the images have a hash on the end. (i.e., assets/image-3414fewafe313.jpg)

asset_path(photo) = assets/photo.jpg (i need the full image path with hash)

How do I reference this image in a view in Rails? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For a view, you can just reference `image_path('photo.jpg')`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

See also `image_tag('photo.jpg')` which produces a full HTML `img` tag.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work. I should have added, I'm trying to add this image link to a Pinterest share link. It just won't render when I try image_tag('photo.jpg'). =/

Comment: @gitastic perhaps you should edit your question and show the actual code you're using and mention things like this that you've already tried. You're more likely to get a helpful answer instead of things you've apparently already tried.

Answer (score 0):

The hash at the end of the asset's URL is the result of having the `config.assets.digest` parameter set to `true`

Quoting from http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production:

> In the production environment Sprockets uses the fingerprinting scheme outlined above. By default Rails assumes assets have been precompiled and will be served as static assets by your web server.
>
> During the precompilation phase an MD5 is generated from the contents of the compiled files, and inserted into the filenames as they are written to disk. These fingerprinted names are used by the Rails helpers in place of the manifest name.